# How to ignore the date and just get information from the times

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I am using the `d/m/y h:m:s` format, and I need to count how many entries I have within the same hour no matter the date.

I was using:

```
=COUNTIFS(H5:H29,">="&TIME(9,0,0),H5:H29,"<="&TIME(9,59,59))
```

But because I have the date in the same cell, it result is 0.

Any way the date information can be ignored?

Comment: Dates are stored as integer days, with times as fractions of a day, so you can extract the time with `MOD(CellAddress,1)`. You may find it easiest to create an additional column for the calculated times and use that in your `COUNTIFS()` formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sumproduct and evaluate the time of day with the Hour() function:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(H5:H29)=9))